# Given a BST we need to check if all the root nodes value is the average of its left and right node. If not delete the root

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree

Given a Binary Search Tree my task is to check whether each node is = to the average of its left node value and right node value or not. if the condition fails the delete the particular node. The bottom up approach would be used as per the given eg i could visualize but the challenge i am facing is that if while coming up that is when stack falls the if condition fails and left child is null i return right child ....if right is null i return left child but what is both are there????
Then what would be the possibility and replacing one child would also change the avg for lower ones so then what?
eg provided was->

```
input:
        10
      /    \
     4      15
    / \       \
   1   9       16
      /
     7
output:
        10
      /    \
     4      16
    / \       
   1   7
```

Someone please help me with the code.

Comment: *"please help me"*: you should edit your question and show the code you are having an issue with, and for which example input it fails or gives the wrong output. If however it is not clear what the code challenge is asking, then we cannot really help. If you have a source for this code challenge, then link to it and quote it literally. That way we can check if you missed something there.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting one approach. Use bottom up approach :

Firstly check if the current node is average of left and right or not. If it is then no problem but if it is not average then delete the current node by seeing these 3 cases: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/

Then do above steps till you reached the root of the tree and this definitely provide a way to the solution.
Correct me if I am wrong in any step.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    
def inOrder(node):
    if node == None:
        return 
    inOrder(node.left)
    print(node.val)
    inOrder(node.right)
    
class Solution:
    def delete(self, root):
        if root.left:
            maxLeftNode = root.left
            while maxLeftNode.right:
                maxLeftNode = maxLeftNode.right
            maxLeftNode.right = root.right
            return root.left
        else:
            return root.right

        
    def trimAvgBST(self, root):
        if root == None:
            return None
        
        #Traverse:
        root.right = self.trimAvgBST(root.right)
        root.left = self.trimAvgBST(root.left)
        
        #Delete
        if root.left == root.right == None:
            return root
        if root.left == None or root.right == None:
            return self.delete(root)
        if root.val != (root.left.val + root.right.val)/2:
            return self.delete(root)
        
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #level 1
    root = TreeNode(10)
    #level 2
    root.left = TreeNode(4)
    root.right = TreeNode(15)
    #level 3
    root.left.left = TreeNode(1)
    root.left.right = TreeNode(9)
    root.right.right = TreeNode(16)
    #level 4
    root.left.right.left = TreeNode(7)
    
    inOrder(Solution().trimAvgBST(root))
```

Comment: Please do not throw some code with no explanation. Explain where the problem was in the question, and explain how does your code solves it. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)